# Correlation matrix for 2d normal variables with components constrained by $y_1 + y_2 = x_1 + x_2$

Tags: correlation, variance, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm following [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Etom/10701_sp11/slides/CCA_tutorial.pdf) tutorial on Canonical Correlation Analysis, and had a question about an example from that tutorial.

**Question:**

On Page 4 of that document, the following example is given:

"Consider two normally distributed two-dimensional variables $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ with unit variance. Let $y_1 + y_2 = x_1
+ x_2$. It is easy to confirm that the correlation matrix between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ is"

\begin{equation*}
R_{xy} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.5 & 0.5 \\
0.5 & 0.5 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

**Attempt:**

I am unclear about how this was derived. My understanding is that the entries in this matrix are $\rho_{i,j}$, ie. they are normalized by the variances of the variables.

For entry (1,1) in the matrix, I wrote out the expression:
$$
\rho_{1,1}= \frac{\mathbb{E}[x_1x_2] - \mathbb{E}[x_1]\mathbb{E}[x_2]}{\sqrt{(Var(x_1)Var(x_2)}}
$$
but I am unclear whether these variables are zero-mean (cancelling out the second term in the numerator) and how to work with $\mathbb{E}[x_1x_2]$ given the constraint on the components.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that your matrix $R$ is only part of the full $4\times 4$ correlation matrix among the four variables.  It can be found by computing the conditional covariance of $x_1+x_2$ and $y_1+y_2$ in two ways, one of which uses the given equality.  Note, too, that you--as well as your reference--need to add a strong assumption to obtain the result: unconditionally, $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$ must all be *uncorrelated.* (If not, the case $x_1=x_2=y_1=y_2$ gives a counterexample.)  It is *not* necessary to assume the distributions are Normal, however.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding the full 4x4 correlation matrix @whuber, the notation used by the reference makes more sense. Could you please give a few more details regarding the conditional covariance setup? I considered using the equation $K_{Y|X} = K_{YY} - K_{YX}K^{-1}_{XX}K_{XY}$ [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Properties) but wasn't sure what the expression for  $K_{Y|X}$ should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key insights are  (a) *Normality is irrelevant*, because the problem concerns correlations only; and therefore (b) *we shouldn't have to rely on formulas for conditional correlations of Normally distributed (vector) random variables.*  What is left, then?  Only the clear parallels (symmetries) between the roles of the $X_i$ and $Y_i.$  This leads directly to a simple solution.

To comport with conventions, I will write the random variables using capital letters.

**Let's suppose $(X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2)$ is a vector random variable with unit covariance matrix:** that is, all marginals have unit variance and otherwise are uncorrelated.  (This adds the assumption of uncorrelation to the problem statement but weakens the Normality assumption.)

The question concerns a conditional covariance for the conditioning event

$$*: X_1+X_2 = Y_1+Y_2.$$

**We will compute the conditional variance in two ways**, both of which exploit the bilinearity of covariance.

1. "Taking out what is known," we may treat $Y_1+Y_2$ as the same as $X_1+X_2,$ whence $$\begin{aligned}\operatorname{Cov}(X_1+X_2, Y_1+Y_2\mid *) &= \operatorname{Cov}(X_1+X_2, X_1+X_2) \\&=\operatorname{Var}(X_1) + 2\operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_2)+\operatorname{Var}(X_2) \\&= 1 + 2(0) + 1 = 2.\end{aligned}$$

   Notice the appearance of the covariance of the $X_i:$ this is one indication of the need for the additional uncorrelation assumption.
2. Using only bilinarity, expand the conditional covariance above as $$\cdots = \operatorname{Cov}(X_1,Y_1\mid *) + \operatorname{Cov}(X_2,Y_1\mid *) + \operatorname{Cov}(X_1,Y_2\mid *) + \operatorname{Cov}(X_2,Y_2\mid *).$$

Note that *the entire problem is symmetric upon (independently) interchanging the $X_i$ or interchanging the $Y_i,$* because such switches (a) do not change the (unconditional) covariance matrix and (b) do not change the conditioning event $*: X_1+X_2=Y_1+Y_2.$  Accordingly, *all four of the terms in $(2)$ are equal.*  Equating $(1)$ and $(2),$ we find that four times any one of those terms equals $2.$  Solving,

$$ \operatorname{Cov}(X_i,Y_j\mid *) = \frac{2}{4} = 0.5$$

for any $i=1,2$ and $j=1,2.$

If we were to arrange this result in matrix form, with rows for $\mathbf X = (X_1,X_2)^\prime$ and columns for $\mathbf Y = (Y_1,Y_2)^\prime,$ it would read

> $$R_{XY}=\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf X, \mathbf Y) \mid *) = \pmatrix{0.5 & 0.5\\0.5 & 0.5}.$$

This equals the correlation $R_{XY}$ because, even after conditioning on $*,$ the variables still have unit variance.

---

**If we do not assume the four original variables are uncorrelated, the result is not generally correct**.  To appreciate this subtlety, let $Z$ be any unit-variance random variable, notice that $(X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2)=(Z,Z,Z,Z)$ satisfies all required conditions in the question, and because $\mathbf X = \mathbf Y$ trivially is always true, compute

$$\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf X, \mathbf Y \mid *) = \pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1}.$$